SCR Power Controller (Phase Angle Firing) with Silicon Carbide (SIC) Heating Elements
I’m working with a 3-phase (208V) SCR power controller (Watlow Power Series) operating in Phase Angle Firing mode with current limiting set to 80A. The setup involves two pairs of silicon carbide heating elements (glow bars) connected in a delta configuration across the three phases.


During phase angle firing, we’re encountering spikes that cause the SCR controller to malfunction and produce errors. I’ve attached an image showing the L1, L2, and L3 on the incoming side of the SCR power controller. The spikes occur when the phase angle firing shifts to the next phase, leading to the controller misinterpreting these spikes as zero-crossing events or loss of load.
Here’s a summary of the troubleshooting steps we've already taken:

3-Phase Filter: No improvement. Isolation Transformer: No improvement; the issue remains on the SCR side of the transformer.
Re-torqued all connections: Ensured all connections are secure. New
100A Breaker: Installed on the main panel feeding this system.
Larger
AWG Wires.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. We’re hoping someone can provide insights or suggest potential causes for these issues. Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE
Here is a sketch with the approximate lengths.
Heaters are silicon carbide (AKA: glowbars).

UPDATE
Update! A load reactor is required between the SCR and the SIC heating elements. Now the question is how many mH inductance is needed. I already tried a .1mH 125A 3 phase reactor (from Fanuc), and it's already made the waveform better.
Thank you!

Have you contacted Watlow? A good manufacture should support their products.

Yes! I did. The product is discontinued. (We have 3 identical SCRs, all doing the same). They told us a few tips, like loose connection, noise from the line, but after seeing the scope images, they are clueless too, what causing this.

You say a filter was tried, but how was it wired? Please show a diagram including mains input, the controller, filter, SCRs and heaters. Also indicate approximate cable lengths between sections.

I added a schematic sketch. Thanks.

Do they require any series inductance or snubber across them?

Nope. This should work as is drawn. But still having those spikes.

Update! A load reactor is required between the SCR and the SIC heating elements. Now the question is how many mH inductance is needed. I already tried a .1mH 125A 3 phase reactor (from Fanuc), and it's already made the waveform better.
